Center text in a cell
I have created some simple Latex code to represent 3 bins that hold balls.  I have probably done this wrong, but I would like to center the names of the bins, A, B and C directly below the cell above.
You can see from the image that the A has been pushed slightly to the left of the 2 balls.

Here is my code:
    \documentclass{article}
%-- Package for mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,wasysym}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   
        \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | c | c | c   }
            %--
            & \newmoon \newmoon &   &  &  &  &  \\
            %--
            \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6}
            %--
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\;\;\;\;} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\;\;\;}{A}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\;\;\;\;} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\;\;\;}{B}  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\;\;\;\;} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\;\;\;}{C}  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\;\;\;\;}
            %--
        \end{tabular}
    \end{equation*}\\
    
\end{document}

Any help appreciated.

I will do that.  Thanks.

You could use fixed-width columns:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,wasysym,array}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   
        \begin{tabular}{ | >{\centering} p{0.5cm} | p{0.25cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{0.25cm} | p{0.5cm} |   }
            %--
            \newmoon \newmoon &   &  &  &   \\
            %--
            \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
            %--
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{A}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B}  &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C}  \\
            %--
        \end{tabular}
    \end{equation*}
    
\end{document}



Or you could use the tabularray package. It makes it easy to specify which lines should be drawn and which should be invisible:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,wasysym,tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={Q[0.6cm]Q[0.25cm]Q[0.6cm]Q[0.25cm]Q[0.6cm]},
      vline{1-Z} = {1}{solid},
      hline{2} = {1,3,5}{solid},
      rowsep=6pt,
      cells={halign=c}
     }
        \newmoon \newmoon &  &  &  &  \\
        A  &  & B  & & C \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}



Thank-you so much.  I am REALLY green at Latex, so your code has given me some homework to do.

@Stephan If you'd like some homework: have a look at the tabularray package. This would make it really easy to specify which lines should be drawn and which lines should be invisible.

Thanks again @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz.  I have seen this package and will try the decipher its contents.  Thanks again for your solution.  I learnt a lot!

@Stephan See my edited answer

So where do I put the tabularray package once I have downloaded and unzipped it.  I use a Macbook Air and TextStudio as my editor.

@Stephan If you have an up-to-date latex installation, it should be included by default.

I'm downloading the latest MacTex 2024 now.  It's been a while since I have updated Latex.  I have the 'old' Tex version on my computer.

You can use fixed width cells, plus a command to place balls.
\documentclass{article}
%-- Package for mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,wasysym}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\balls}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} \\ #1 \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   
  \begin{tabular}{ | w{c}{2em} | w{c}{1em} | w{c}{2em} | w{c}{1em} | w{c}{2em} | }
    %--
    \balls{\newmoon\newmoon} & & & & \\
    %--
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
    %--
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{A}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{B}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
    
\begin{equation*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}   
  \begin{tabular}{ | w{c}{2em} | w{c}{1em} | w{c}{2em} | w{c}{1em} | w{c}{2em} | }
    %--
    \balls{\newmoon \\ \newmoon\newmoon} & & \balls{\newmoon} & & \\
    %--
    \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5}
    %--
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{A}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{B}
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
    
\end{document}



Thank-you.  I like this method.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,wasysym}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[columns-width=5mm]
\Block[borders={left,bottom,right}]{}{} \newmoon\newmoon && 
\Block[borders={left,bottom,right}]{}{} && 
\Block[borders={left,bottom,right}]{}{} \\
A          && B          && \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


Of course, it's possible to have a code a bit shorter by defining a new command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,wasysym}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MyBox}{\Block[borders={left,bottom,right}]{}{}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[columns-width=5mm]
\MyBox \newmoon\newmoon && \MyBox && \MyBox \\
A          && B          && \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

The output is the same.

Thank-you.  Very nice.  Very much appreciated.
